# Location tracked after signing into network using hotspot

Tags: ios, network, wifi, geolocation

I recently signed into a friends Wi-Fi network using her hotspot (∞) i.e. infinity symbol rather than Wi-Fi. Now it seems, she can always see my location-is this expected and if so, how do I stop this?!

Comment: how can you login to wifi through a hotspot? also, where can she see the location? IMO this is *very* unexpected

Comment: I was with her at the time I logged on to it. It’s the little infinity sign on iPhone that lets you use Wi-Fi from a network.

Comment: So if phone A enables the hotspot, phone B can connect to phone A wirelessly. However, all (internet) data from phone A goes through its mobile coverage (**not** WiFi). Neither does phone B have any connection to any WiFi. It is only connected to the phone A via the hotspot. I.e. all internet requests from phone B go to phone A, from there to the internet and same route back.

Comment: You cannot sign in to someones WiFi through a hotspot. It is not possible. Further, what do you mean by "she can see my location"? Where can she see it? How accurate? Does it always work?....?